# Example of nonconvex function with nonempty subgradient

Tags: calculus, optimization

I understand subgradient is well defined for convex functions such as $f(x)=|x|$ but not for nonconvex functions. I don't have a good intuition how subgradient is defined for a nonconvex function. Can someone please provide a simple example that subgradient does exist for a nonconvex function? I tried to search but without success. Of course somebody have asked questions involving keywords nonconvex and subgradient, but that doesn't mean the same question.

Comment: I was aware of that post and don't believe that's the same question. But why did you think that's a duplicate? Did that post provide an answer for the above question?

Comment: The first comment on the linked post answers your question: the subgradient definition is the same for non-convex functions. So any non-convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ can have a subgradient. e.g. $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ has a subgradient of $\{0\}$ at $0$. With that said, the subgradient is often empty for non-convex functions, and isn't very useful (most theorems about sub-gradients only apply to non-convex functions).

Comment: I have changed the title and look for an example of nonempty subgradient of nonconvex functions. In your comment, did you mean any convex (not non-convex) function can have a subgradient?

Comment: No, I meant any function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ (either non-convex or convex) can have a subgradient. The subgradient is not exclusively defined for convex functions: it is also defined for non-convex function. The example I gave is non-convex: $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$. It has a non-empty sub-gradient at the origin (of $\{0\}$). and $g(x)=kx+\sqrt{|x|}$ has subgradient of $\{k\}$ at the origin, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful explanations.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome.